# Create vs Edit variable permission - Octopus Deploy

Tags: octopus-deploy

I see an edit variable permission that is scoped to the environment.  However, it seems like who ever is responsible for setting up the project, would be responsible for creating the variables, where some other security entity would be responsible for only modifying the values, specifically the secure ones.  Is this possible?

Edit:
Adding a little more, I suppose I'm asking for permissions based on the project variable set.  Only those with the "EditProjectVariableSet" permission would be able to add or remove variables from the project.

Edit:
Added uservoice:
https://octopusdeploy.uservoice.com/forums/170787-general/suggestions/18022360-separate-permission-for-editing-variable-values-wi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `Configuration`->`Teams` there is a link to `Roles`.

[image]

You could create a new role, for ex: `Variable Editor` and only assign `VariableEdit`, `VariableEditUnscoped`, `VariableView`, `VariableViewUnscoped`.

However I don't think you can restrict to a modification only.

Comment: I figured that might be the answer for now.  Hopefully there is a new feature in our future..